# sqlite server on apple server?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am doing sqlite with iphone development, right now the db files are on my macbook. My question is when I submit it to the app store, where the db resides? Is it on apple's server or on each user's device?

Answer (score 1):

No data resides on Apples Server. Databases will either reside in the document directory or inside your application bundle (you could also use a web service to access data from a database). Perhaps you should have a look at [SQLite 101 for iPhone Developers: Creating and Scripting](http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-creating-and-scripting) and [SQLite 101 for iPhone Developers: Making Our App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app)

Comment: Thank you both.  I thought sqlite is the same as sql server. Now my sql server database is hosted on godaddy, how do I access it via iphone development on my macbook (not submit to the app store yet).

Answer (score 0):

Just tink a very-very lille bit!
if it would be at apple server, and if a novice programmer would write an infinite loop while generating his test data what would happen? :)

It is in your phone / device.